# WP7 not picking new Application Icon

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons

I have created a new Application icon to represent my WP7 app and set it with the app using the 'Properties' option for the project.  I have double checked that the change has been implemented by checking the WMManifest.XML

```
  <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Class Timetable Icon 62px.png</IconPath>
```

I have rebuilt the solution and been in and out of VS10 but the new icon is not displayed as the app icon.  This occurs foe the emulator and when I deploy to the phone.

I have even replaced the default ApplicationIcon.png file with my new icon but its still not being picked up.

Any ideas???

Comment: I would try avoiding spaces in the path as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - got it sorted.  The issue was that the icon needed to be in the root directory of the application.  I had them in my own sub directory, which didn't give any errors, but, simply didn't display them.

Its in point 27 of http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/gg317447  where the limitation (of having to use them from the root directory) is mentioned.

This is all under 7.0 - possibly maybe more flexible under 7.1.

Comment: I had the exact same issue a week ago and found the same thing - it needs to be in the root directory.

Comment: Is it the same under 7.1  or it just a 7.0 issue.??

Comment: 7.0 issue. I haven't tested under 7.5

Answer (score 3):

You should uninstall the application from the Emulator and try this again. Also try shutting down the emulator and starting it again to see if the issue persists.

Also ensure that the Build Action for your PNG is set to Content.

Comment: Tip: When holding down the icon, it'll refresh and display the new one. But it won't actually appear until after a restart, and/or re-pin.

Comment: Even when holding it down I don't see the new one.     It strange because I have overwritten the default Icon with my Icon as well - and yet still it displays the std one.   Interstingly, in the process of trying some of the ideas raised I removed my new Icon and when I tried to run to the emulator, it objected as it could not find my file..... so it does seem to be aware of it.  But does not seem o be prepared to display it.  Its a straightforward 62X62 png file - could there be an issue woith it causing a default one to be displayed?

Comment: Did you try with a filename that didn't include spaces? :p

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your new icon file to your phone application Project and when you select it in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio make sure that its Build property is set to Content.

Comment: If you've got the WP7.1 RC SDK try the Marketplace Test Kit (right click on your project and select it). The first test is about icons and may point out your problem.

Comment: Thanks - I have not yet upgraded to the 7.1 SDK - I was just finishing a few things and was then going to upgrade.  But, seems like I may be better upgrading now.